# C# Is it possible to run nunit tests inside ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nunit

I have a very simple question.

Is it possible to run Nunit tests inside an asp.net web app?

Here is an example project:

- MyApp -> ASP.Net app (.net5)
- MyTests -> Nunit Tests (.net5)

My Asp.net project (`MYApp`) contains all my controllers and such, with a depency on `NUnit.Engine` and my test project.
There is another Test project (`MyTests`), which is just a dummy project.

I want to be able to run in a controller, inside my web app, my tests.

Example controller:

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/tests")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController: ControllerBase
    {
        // Some helper class to verify everything is working somehow
        private class ReportListener : ITestEventListener
        {
            public void OnTestEvent(string report)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(report);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Trigger()
        {
            try
            {
                using ITestEngine engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();
                engine.Initialize();
                engine.WorkDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "../","MyTests/");
                // Create a simple test package - one assembly, no special settings
                TestPackage package = new TestPackage(@".\bin\Debug\net5.0\MyTests.dll"); //Just for debugging and testing
                
                // Get a runner for the test package
                using ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package);
                runner.Load();
                
                // Run all the tests in the assembly
                XmlNode testResult = runner.Run(listener: new ReportListener(), TestFilter.Empty);
                var outputs = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
                foreach (XmlNode elem in testResult.SelectNodes("//test-case/output"))
                {
                    outputs = outputs.Append(elem.InnerText);
                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
            return Ok();
        }
        
    }
}
```

But unfortunately all my attemps so far have failed.

Am I missing something?
Is Nunit.Engine not made to be run in an asp.net context?

I am building all this in .NET5.0 (company policy)

If needed I can provide an example project

Answer (score 0):

There could be more, but one small thing would explain the failure...

The NUnit engine defaults to running tests in a separate process, which it launches. So, assuming that your code is working correctly as written, a ProcessRunner will be created and the engine will communicate with it, telling it to run your tests.

This could fail in one of two ways:

1. You may not have permission to create a process.
2. If you succeed in creating it, the code will definitely **not** be running in the asp.net context. In that case, it would probably error out and terminate with very little debug information provided.

A simple fix is to add a setting to the test package, telling the engine to run the tests in process.

```
TestPackage package = new TestPackage(@".\bin\Debug\net5.0\MyTests.dll");
package.AddSetting("ProcessModel", "InProcess");
```

If you get a second error after doing this, it should at least result in a clearer message and you should be able to debug through the code.

Comment: HI!
Well unfortunately that didn't help :/ ....
- I do have access rights to spawn new processes (i'm running the app on my dev machine).

I thaught using the EngineApi would be smarter, but I could just spawn a process myself to run the tests...

Comment: But did you add the setting as I suggested? In order to run in the proper context, I don't think you want to create a process at all.